# When I add .push function in my code for loop breaks

Tags: javascript, for-loop, vue.js

I had an array which has all orders with details(order-time, order-details, prices etc.), I want to find total prices for each month and get them all in an array.

```
  data(){
    checks:[//there is data from database]
    months:["2019-01","2019-02","2019-03","2019-04","2019-05","2019-06","2019-07","2019-08","2019-09","2019-10","2019-11","2019-12"],
    monthlyTotal:0,
    monthlyTotalsArr:[]
  },
  computed:{
   calcTotalMonthly(){
     for(let i=0; i<this.months.length; i++){
            this.checks.forEach((item => {
               if(item.orderTime.includes(this.months[i])){
                 item.bill.forEach(prod => {
                   this.monthlyTotal += parseInt(prod.price);
                 });
               }    
             }));
              this.monthlyTotalsArr.push(this.monthlyTotal);
             this.monthlyTotal = 0; 
         } return this.monthlyTotalsArr;

   }
  }
```

When I run this had an error `[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.`, and `monthlyTotalsArr.length` will be like 1220.

If I delete `this.monthlyTotalsArr.push(this.monthlyTotal);` and `console.log(this.monthlyTotal);` i just saw 12 results as it's supposed to be, but I do not know why the `push` function breaks the loop.This is my problem, finally I want to see 12 different elements in `monthlyTotalsArr`.

Comment: `this.monthlyTotal += parseInt(prod.price);` the `this` in this code is different than in `this.monthlyTotalsArr.push(this.monthlyTotal);`

Comment: what is the different i can not see ?

Comment: While the answer I've provided below is a good change to make, I'm no longer convinced that it fully explains why you're getting an infinite update loop. I think there'd also need to be a problem somewhere in your template to cause that message. If possible could you include the code for your template, especially any sections that reference `monthlyTotalsArr` or `calcTotalMonthly`? If the template is large I suggest stripping it down to something more minimal before posting, being careful to check that the warning remains.

Answer (score 1):

A computed property should not have side effects. In this case you are modifying both `monthlyTotal` and `monthlyTotalsArr`. There's no need to do that, you can just use local variables inside the function and then return the computed value.

What's happening is that `monthlyTotalArr` is being registered as a dependency of this computed property. But you're then immediately changing it, which will mark the computed property as needing recalculating. It keeps going round in a loop trying to recalculate it but every time its dependencies change and it needs to go round again.

You should be able to write it something like this:

```js
calcTotalMonthly () {
  return this.months.map(month => {
    let monthlyTotal = 0

    for (const check of this.checks) {
      if (check.orderTime.includes(month)) {
        for (const prod of check.bill) {
          monthlyTotal += parseInt(prod.price)
        }
      }    
    }

    return monthlyTotal
  })
}
```

I've swapped the `forEach` calls to `for`/`of` loops. That isn't required but I think it makes it easier to follow. The main loop I've swapped to use `map` as that seems to be what it's really doing.

You can rename `calcTotalMonthly` to `monthlyTotalsArr` if that's how you want to refer to that array elsewhere. The `data` properties `monthlyTotal` and `monthlyTotalsArr` are both removed in my version.

I haven't attempted to address the potential performance problem from having 3 nested loops.